# Lager test logging from the console

Tags: console, erlang, runtime, read-eval-print-loop, lager

Lets say I attach to a running Erlang application and I change the lager configuration from the console, by running:

`lager:set_loglevel(lager_console_backend,"console.log", debug).`

I then want to test it by issuing a command like:

`lager:debug(<<"test">>).`

But that won't work because Lager is implemented using parse tranformation at compile time.

Surely there must is a more verbose command which *will* work. Does such an instruction exist?

Answer (score 3):

Solution, used the backwards compatable log API (without the parse transform).

`(dev1@127.0.0.1)4> lager:log(error, "console", "foo").
ok`

Verified it worked, using `tail -f`:

`tail -f ./dev1/logs/console.log
2014-07-29 17:12:21.255 [error]  foo`